# How to restrict access to an azure app service for certain subdomains

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created an App service and run a Docker image and I would like to allow only certain url to access it.

To be more specific I am running the docker image of https://shields.io/ which provides the badges for my OS project hosted in GitHub. So what I am looking for is to allow only all repositories of my GitHub organization e.g https://github.com/myorganization/repo1, https://github.com/myorganization/repo2 to request service from the Azure app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve that with just an app service. I think a URL will be easily spoofed. I suggest looking at securing a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/). What you can do is create a function or logic app that can verify the hash you've configured for webhook. If it matches, you can forward the request to your app service. To protect the app service, you can add it and the function app to a [Vnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#new-vnet-integration) and restrict traffic so that your docker app only receives traffic from the function app.